Where is z_uncompress and z_compress defined in zlib?
I am building a C++ project that uses zlib, and I get this error:
undefined symbol: z_uncompress
undefined symbol: z_compress

I investigated it further, and I've found this reference in zconf
#  ifndef Z_SOLO
#    define compress              z_compress
#    define compress2             z_compress2
#    define compressBound         z_compressBound
#  endif

I am not able to locate z_compress or find out why the linker can not find it. Is it in an other library?

Those #defines apply to the source code that defines compress as well. Are you sure you are linking a zlib that was compiled with Z_SOLO off? Check with nm to be sure.

That's only if zlib is compiled with Z_PREFIX, which puts z_ in front of all of the external symbols. You need to make sure that the headers you are including match the library you are linking.
